# R data.fame manipulation: convert to NA after specific column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply, radix

I have a large `data.frame` and I need some conversion based by row. My purpose is convert all values in rows to `NA` after if there is specific character in column.

For example I provide little sample from my real data set:

```
sample_df <- data.frame( a = c("V","I","V","V"), b = c("I","V","V","V"), c = c("V","V","I","V"),  d = c("V","V","I","V"))


result_df <- data.frame( a = c("V","I","V","V"), b = c("I",NA,"V","V"), c = c(NA,NA,"I","V"), d = c(NA,NA,NA,"V"))
```

As an example in `sample_df` 
First I want to turn all values to NA after first "I"

[Sample data.frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcvXN.png)

I tried `base`, `dpylr`, `purrr` but can not create an algorithm.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My Solution:**

After @Julien Navarre recommendation, first I created `toNA()` function:

```
toNA <- function(x) {

  temp <- grep("INVALID", unlist(x)) # which can be generalized for any string

  lt <- length(x)
  loc <- min(temp,100)+1 #100 is arbitrary number bigger than actual column count

  #print(lt) #Debug purposes 

  if( (loc < lt+1) ) {
    x[ (loc):(lt)] <-NA
  }

  x

}
```

First, I tried `plyr::adply()` and `purrrlyr::by_row()` functions to apply my `toNA()` function my data.frame which has over 3 million rows.

Both are very slow. (For 1000 rows they take 9 and 6 seconds respectively). These approaches are also slow with a simple `function(x) x`. I am not sure what is overhead.

So I tried `base::apply()` function: (`result` is my data set)

```
as.tibble(t(apply(result, 1,  toNA ) ))
```

It only takes 0.2 seconds for 1000 rows.

I am not sure about programming style but for now this solution works for me.

Thanks for all your recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Find "I" values

```
I_true<-sample_df=="I"
I_true
         a     b     c     d
[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Find positions from the first "I" seen

```
out<-t(apply(t(I_true),2,cumsum))
    out
     a b c d
[1,] 0 1 1 1
[2,] 1 1 1 1
[3,] 0 0 1 2
[4,] 0 0 0 0
```

Replace needed values

```
 output<-out
 output[out>=1]<-NA 
 output[output==0]<-"V"
 output[I_true]<-"I"
 output[out>=2]<-NA
```

Your output

```
output
     a   b   c   d  
[1,] "V" "I" NA  NA 
[2,] "I" NA  NA  NA 
[3,] "V" "V" "I" "I"
[4,] "V" "V" "V" "V"
```

Example 2:

```
sample_df <- data.frame( a = c("V","I","I","V"), b = c("I","V","V","V"), c = c("V","V","I","V"), d = c("V","V","I","V"))
sample_df
  a b c d
1 V I V V
2 I V V V
3 I V I I
4 V V V V
output
     a   b   c   d  
[1,] "V" "I" NA  NA 
[2,] "I" NA  NA  NA 
[3,] "I" NA  NA  NA 
[4,] "V" "V" "V" "V"
```

Comment: This solution works good for the sample data, but I think will not work if there is more than one "I" in a row

Comment: Row three has 2 "I"

Comment: Thanks for you reply. My actual values contains "INVALID||..."  so I am using grepl or str_detect to find "INVALID" tag : I am using grepl("INVALID", real_data_set) but it only returns vector. How can I extend first step to grepl?Second, @Antonis offered sample_df not working correctly

Comment: right but check this example: `sample_df <- data.frame( a = c("V","I","I","V"), b = c("I","V","V","V"), c = c("V","V","I","V"),  d = c("V","V","I","V"))`

Comment: @DenizTopcu is it realistic the example above?

Comment: Yes. But my actual data is complicated so only write as "I" and "V

Comment: Perfect, assigne the answer to close the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force approach, which should be the easiest to come up with but the least preferred. Anyway, here it is:

```
df <- data.frame( a = c("V","I","V","V"), b = c("I","V","V","V"), c = c("V","V","I","V"),  d = c("V","V","I","V"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
rowlength<-length(colnames(df))
for (i in 1:length(df[,1])){
   if (any(as.character(df[i,])=='I')){
      first<-which(as.character(df[i,])=='I')[1]+1
      df[i,first:rowlength]<-NA
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible answer using `ddply` from the `plyr` package

```
ddply(sample_df,.(a,b,c,d), function(x){
  idx<-which(x=='I')[1]+1 #ID after first 'I'
  if(!is.na(idx)){    #Check if found
    if(idx<=ncol(x)){  # Prevent out of bounds
      x[,idx:ncol(x)]<-NA
    }

  }
  x
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `plyr` approach :

```
plyr::adply(sample_df, 1L, function(x) { 
  if (all(x != "I")) 
    return(x)
  x[1L:min(which(x == "I"))]
})
```

You have to use an `if` because `x[min(which(x == "I"))]` would returns `numeric(0)` for rows without at least one `I`

Comment: toNA <- function(x)
{
    a_temp <- map_lgl(x, function (x) str_detect(x, "INVALID"))
    
    if(any(a_temp)) {
      
      #print (which(a_temp))
      x[ (min(which(a_temp))+1):(length(x)-2)  ] <- NA
      
      return(x)
      
    }
    
    return(x)
    
}

Comment: I wrote this function. But it is to slow because my dataframe has 3million row and 20 column. Do you have any recomendation? Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

A pure base solution, we're building a boolean matrix of "`=="I"` or not", then with a double cumsum by row we can find where our `NAs` must be placed:

```
result_df <- sample_df
is.na(result_df) <- t(apply(sample_df == "I",1,function(x) cumsum(cumsum(x)))) >1

result_df 
#   a    b    c    d
# 1 V    I <NA> <NA>
# 2 I <NA> <NA> <NA>
# 3 V    V    I <NA>
# 4 V    V    V    V
```